# Maximizing the number of combinations of a sum of integers

Tags: optimization, combinatorics

Basically, given a sorted list of positive non-zero numbers, say {1, 4, 5}, change a single number in the list to maximize the distinct combinations possible. The above gives
1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, that is, six combinations. If we were to change 4 to 2 so we have {1, 2, 5}, we'd get 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, that is, seven combinations.

I need to find a number x to add to a single number of the list to maximize the amount of combinations. x should be the smallest abslout value, we can both add or subtract.

I've done it using brute force by enumeration, which runs in many times exponential time. So it's not feasible for larger problems. Now I need to do it fast.

Just checking the number of combinations is exponential time? And I have to find the exact optimal solution.

What would be some keywords for solving this problem? I've attempted to find a recurrence, so I could use dynamic programming and some sort of branch and bound to limit the explosion, but it's no use.

I've looked into problems like [cutting mill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem), [subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), and a lot of other combinatorial optimization problems to see if I could find some ideas. But I don't get it. Simply verifying the solution is exponential time.

Comment: Note that 2^|numberset| is your upper limit (if you include the empty subset).  One way of ensuring it (obviously not always possible) is to make every number in the set a different power of some particular integer.

Comment: (+1) Interesting question. I only wish more effort went into the spelling and grammar, so that it would not require three other people to edit it in order to beat it into shape.

Comment: Is the goal to minimise the number combinations which add up to another number in the set? For example, your first set can only be improved because two of the numbers already add up to the third one?

Comment: You could look at using Excel's Solver do the hard work for you. See this similar question which finds the [best combination of numbers to make a total](http://superuser.com/q/362349/98141)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a stab at it, I've written no code or even worked out any proofs on it.

Since you're limited to changing only one value, I would consider that the easiest way to *eliminate* combinations (which I know you're not trying to do, but hear me out) is to make two numbers add up to another number in the list. So in your example `1 4 5` because `1 + 4 = 5` you lose out on combinations there. Therefore I would do a query of the set of numbers for what number pairs result in another member of the set. This is `O(n^2 lg n)` as you compare each number to every other number, and in doing so also search the (sorted) list of numbers to find if it exists or not.

Your candidate is that which has the highest number of 'collisions'. Hands down, by making the highest collision-prone number a zero-collision number, you will get the maximum increase in end results. From there, it is just a matter of finding what number to add/subtract to it to make it a non-collision number. I haven't worked out the proper way to do this, but I suspect it can be done with dynamic programming in polynomial time.

There lies another serious problem in which you have ties. I think this is in the worst case going to add an extra `*n` to your complexity, as you will have at most `n` ties to simultaneously search. So assuming you can calculate the above problem in `n^p` time where p is some constant polynomial, then the entire problem should still be solveble in `n^(p+1)` time.

This is certainly a doosy of a problem, and I hope this has been able to shed some light onto it. After two months, someone has to take a stab at it, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the question had been: for any value of n, what n positive integers give the maximum number of combinations. The answer to this question is: 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, ... 2^(n-1).

The proof is straightforward because:

- with this set you can create every integer between 2^0 and (2^n)-1.
- this set sums to (2^n)-1.

Consider {1, 2, 4}.  The combination are: 1, 2, 1+2, 4, 1+4, 2+4 and 1+2+4.  1+2+4 = 7.

It seems reasonable to suggest that for any set you maximise the number of combinations by making the set as similar as possible to 2^0, 2^1, ...

I am not sure what "as similar as possible" means. However, {1, 2, 5} is closer to {1, 2, 4} that {1, 4, 5}. Is this true of the other sets you have investigated by brute force?

I notice that {1, 2, 5} is one away from {1, 2, 4} and has one less combination. Is this a coincidence?

If these observations stand up to examination, I suspect they will not be too difficult to prove. Even if you cannot prove them, they may give you an algorithm that works.

Comment: I don't think your proof complete.  The series `x^i` for any `x` have an equal number of unique powerset sums, do they not?

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned that any x^i series will have the same maximum number of combinations. The 2^i series is unique only in that the combinations are a consecutive series of integers.  In fact any series where x(n) + x(n+1) < x(n+2) will have the same maximum.  I still think that understanding the nature of an optimal adjusted series will be a useful first step.